# SQL sum case group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a relatively simple query and now have to make what appears to be simple change to that query.  It's not going very well though.

The query:

```
select filekey, eventdate, hourstype, hours from hourshist
```

yields the following results:

```
filekey eventdate hourstype hours
1       6/1/2018   1          9
1       6/1/2018   2          3
1       6/2/2018   1          8
```

Which was fine until a change was requested that stated if hourstype 1 and 2 occur on the same day hourstype remains as 1 and hours (with type 1 or 2) are summed.  Any other hourstype (3,4,5,etc.) would not be summed and would show as its own row.  Days that have either hourstype 1 or 2 but not both should not change at all. It should yield the following results:

```
filekey eventdate hourstype hours
1       6/1/2018   1          12
1       6/2/2018   1          8
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tip of today: `GROUP BY`!

Comment: Add some more sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: Learn how to ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid over-complicating your aggregation by using case statements I would use two queries and a union to keep it fairly simple. The following produces your desired results in my environment.

```
SELECT filekey, eventdate, 1 AS 'hourstype', SUM(hours) AS 'hours' FROM hourshist
WHERE hourstype IN (1,2)
GROUP BY filekey, eventdate
UNION
SELECT filekey, eventdate, hourstype, hours FROM hourshist
WHERE hourstype NOT IN (1,2);
```

I used the following to create the test environment you described:

```
CREATE TABLE hourshist
(
filekey INT,
eventdate DATE,
hourstype INT,
hours INT
);

INSERT INTO hourshist
VALUES (1,'6/1/2018',1,9)
,(1,'6/1/2018',2,3)
,(1,'6/2/2018',1,8);
```